# Pushforward of sheaves on the blowup of $\mathbb A^2$ to $\mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

In http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2564 Example 4.12 it is written that for $Y$ the blowup of $\mathbb A^2$ at the origin (i.e. $Y \cong \mathrm{Tot} \, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1} (-1)$), and $π \colon Y \to \mathbb P^1$ the projection, we have

$$
π_∗ (\mathcal O_Y) \cong \bigoplus_{p≤0} \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1} (−1)^{⊗p} = \bigoplus_{k≥0} \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1} (k)
$$

I don't understand how to derive the first isomorphism.

More generally, given any other coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $Y$ (or on any other scheme/variety $X$ with an affine morphism $X \to \mathbb P^1$) is there a general method of finding its pushforward under $π$?

Comment: As you said, $Y\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ is the line bundle defined by the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. So $Y=\mathbf{Spec}\mathrm{Sym}\mathcal{O}(-1)^\vee$. This give the isomorphism.

Comment: @Roland Could you explain how the pushforward is related to the symmetric tensor?

Comment: This is just the global spec construction : if $E=\mathbf{Spec}\mathcal{A}$, for an $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_E=\mathcal{A}$ (where $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ is the structural morphism).

Comment: This is just a globalization of the affine case : if $\pi:\operatorname{Spec}B\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A$, the $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B}=B$ seen as an $A$-module (or rather as an $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}$-module.)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still missing how globalization is related to the symmetric tensor.

Comment: Do you know the correspondance between vector bundles and locally free sheaf ? If $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally free sheaf on $X$, then the corresponding vector bundle is $\operatorname{\mathbf{Spec}}\operatorname{Sym}\mathcal{E}^\vee$. I just applied it with $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{O}(-1)$. You get the algebra $\operatorname{Sym}\mathcal{O}(-1)^\vee$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Take the global spec to get $Y$ and apply my second comment to get the push-forward.